# How to return Future<Widget> as Widget

Tags: flutter, dart, layout, widget

The code below might seem a bit complicated, though basically the function below uses a switch case to return the correct widget based on the index number of the navigation bar. The problem which i am facing, is that, when the body of the scaffold has to get the correct page according to the index number of the navigation bar, it tells me that i cannot have a type of `Future <Widget>`
instead of a type of Widget as the body of my scaffold. I expected this to happen however, i do not know how to add the await keyword, so that the type is a valid widget. Thanks for your help. PS. Please see the comments, it tells where i want to call the function in the below code.

```
Future<Widget> getCorrespondingPage(int index) async {
    bool isFromGoogleSignIn;
    String displayName = await InformationFinder().getUserName(_auth);
    String provider = await ProviderFinder().getProvider(_auth);
    String profilePicture = await InformationFinder().getProfilePicture(_auth);
    if (provider == 'Google') {
      setState(() {
        isFromGoogleSignIn = true;
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        isFromGoogleSignIn = false;
      });
    }
    switch (index) {
      case 0:
        return SideBarLayoutStateful(
          app: SmartVetScreen(),
          isFromGoogleSignIn: isFromGoogleSignIn,
          profilePicture: profilePicture,
          displayName: displayName,
        );
        break;
      case 1:
        return SideBarLayoutStateful(
          app: SmartReminderScreen(),
          isFromGoogleSignIn: isFromGoogleSignIn,
          profilePicture: profilePicture,
          displayName: displayName,
        );
      default:
        return null;
    }
  }
```

This is my completed stateful widget:

```
class _NavigationBarScreenState extends State<NavigationBarScreen> {
  int currentIndex = 0;
//THIS IS WHERE THE ABOVE FUNCTION WAS CREATED
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          currentIndex: currentIndex,
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.shifting,
          iconSize: 27.0,
          elevation: 10.0,
          selectedFontSize: 18.0,
          unselectedFontSize: 15.0,
          items: [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.stethoscope),
              title: Text('Smart Vet'),
              backgroundColor: Colors.green.shade200,
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.bell),
              title: Text('Smart Remind'),
              backgroundColor: Colors.purple.shade100,
            ),
          ],
          onTap: (index) {
            setState(() {
              currentIndex = index;
            });
          },
        ),
//THIS IS WHERE I NEED TO GET BACK THE WIDGET FROM THE getCorrespondingPage() method
        body: ,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Futures will have to be awaited. In your case you're using futures in a rendering process, and since the process have started when you're waiting for the future due to the fact that the future is in the middle of the widget tree, you have to wait the future from the widget tree using some special method. You can use `FutureBuilder` for that.

Separate the data fetching and widget rendering and use `FutureBuilder` to await for the `Future`.

```dart
Future<Map<String, String>> getData() async {
  String displayName = await InformationFinder().getUserName(_auth);
  String provider = await ProviderFinder().getProvider(_auth);
  String profilePicture = await InformationFinder().getProfilePicture(_auth);

  return {
    'displayName': displayName,
    'provider': provider,
    'profilePicture': profilePicture
  };
}

Widget getCorrespondingPage(int index) {
  return FutureBuilder<Map<String, String>>(
    future: getData,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        final displayName = snapshot.data['displayName'];
        final provider = snapshot.data['provider'];
        final profilePicture = snapshot.data['profilePicture'];

        bool isFromGoogleSignIn = provider == 'google';
        switch (index) {
          case 0:
            return SideBarLayoutStateful(
              app: SmartVetScreen(),
              isFromGoogleSignIn: isFromGoogleSignIn,
              profilePicture: profilePicture,
              displayName: displayName,
            );
            break;
          case 1:
            return SideBarLayoutStateful(
              app: SmartReminderScreen(),
              isFromGoogleSignIn: isFromGoogleSignIn,
              profilePicture: profilePicture,
              displayName: displayName,
            );
          default:
            return null;
        }
      }
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, though could you explain in more detail how that works?